# How do I capture the select event for a jquery ui autocomplete if it has images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0p7g93uy/1/). I am trying to create an autocomplete with images and when the user selects an image then I want to capture that event but for some reason it doesn't work with images:

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
          //source: tags,
          source: images,
          minLength: 1,
          delay: 0,
          open: function(){
            $('.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a').css('word-wrap','break-word');
          },
          close: function () { $('.ui-autocomplete').show() },
          focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
          },
          select: function(event, ui){
            alert("here there");
            return false;
          }
        }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
         //return $('<li style="margin-bottom:2px;"></li>').data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<a>hi there</a>').appendTo(ul);
         return $('<li style="margin-bottom:2px;"></li>').data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<a><img src="' + item + '" style="width:115px;"/></a>').appendTo(ul);
        };
```

If I instead return just plain text (just uncomment that part in the above code) I can capture the select event but it doesn't work with images? I have also set the z-index with no luck.

EDIT: I corrected the jsfiddle link

Comment: It seems like you've given the wrong JSFiddle link.

Comment: Oh yeah that would help! I've corrected it thanks!

Comment: the select event is the same yet I think you need to render your menu items correctly to ensure they trigger the event properly. See this example: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data it's item, `<li>`, has a `<div>` inside for content wrapping. Yours does not and it should not be an `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some text inside the list:

```
return $('<li style="margin-bottom:2px;">'+item.label+'</li>').data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<a><img src="' + item + '" style="width:115px;"/></a>').appendTo(ul);
```

Then, You can hide the text by setting:

```
li {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

and adjust the `.ui-state-active` by setting:

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise the following:

```
.data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $('<li style="margin-bottom:2px;"></li>').data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<div><img src="' + item.label + '" style="width:215px;"/></div>').appendTo(ul);
});
```

Since you're using `<a>`, it's click event is bubbling up first and this does not allow the click to target the `<li>` and thus not trigger `select`.

Example using DIV: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/napvj856/28/

Comment: hmmm. this doesn't seem to correct it: https://jsfiddle.net/at7ck1pj/

Comment: @user_78361084 I updated my answer. You need to call `item.label`. I would consider switching to an Object too where the label are search terms and the value is the IMG URL.